# Trigger tcpListner event in worker role after database update in wcf service

Tags: azure, tcpclient, tcplistener, wc

i am listening tcpport in my workerole and hosted it in azure cloud service.

WorkerRole is basically to send updates to connected devices whenever any database transaction are made through wcf service

wcf service is hosted sepertelly in azure web sites.

How can i trigger tcplistner whenever any update is made in database through wcf service call for example method XYZ.

Worker role code

```
private AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public override void Run()
    {
        TcpListener listener = null;

        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(
                RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["LiveUpdateEP"].IPEndpoint);
            listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;

            listener.Start();   


        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Trace.Write("Echo server could not start.", "Error");
            return;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, listener);
            connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }


    }


    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
            return base.OnStart();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 

    }


    private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Accept connection
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
        TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
        connectionWaitHandle.Set();

        // Accepted connection
        Guid clientId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string Description = "Updated Items list :: ";


        // Setup reader/writer
        var data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();
        StreamWriter writer;



        NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
        writer = new StreamWriter(netStream);

        int readCount;
        readCount = netStream.Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        dataString.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, readCount));

        try
        {

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            Updates objUpdate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Updates>(dataString.ToString());

            dataString.Clear();
            dataString.Append(" Database WR - " + objUpdate.DBName);
            dataString.Append(" DeviceId WR - " + objUpdate.DeviceId);
            dataString.Append(" Date WR- " + objUpdate.Lud);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dataString.Append(ex.Message);
        }

        EventWaitHandle dbTriggerEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset,
                                      "DB_Update_Trigger_Event");

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                Description = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                string dataToWrite = Description + "---" + dataString;


                writer.WriteLine(dataToWrite);
                dbTriggerEvent.WaitOne();


            //    EventWaitHandle dbTriggerEvent1 = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset,
            //                         "DB_Update_Trigger_Event");
              //  dbTriggerEvent1.Set();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }



        }




        // Done!
        client.Close();
    }
```

Wcf service methods:

```
 public WSResponseObject TCP_Test(string Item_Name)
{
    WSResponseObject response = new WSResponseObject();
    try
    {
        Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.IsError = -1;
        response.Data = ex.Message;
    }
    response.Data = "DONE";
    return response;
}
 public void Run()
{
    TcpListener listener = null;
    AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    try
    {
        IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xx.xx.xxx");

        int port = 10950;
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, port);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(ip);
        connectionWaitHandle.Set();

        string msg = @"{""DeviceId"" : ""Test Device 11111"",""BranchId"" : ""11"",""DBName"" : ""Test DB2222"",""Lud"" : ""2014-01-15 05:43:43 +0000""}";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);

        int length = bytes.Length;
        byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
        NetworkStream Streamm = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Streamm);
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine(msg);


    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }




}
```